# How does this obfuscated Perl work?

Tags: perl

```
    #!/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    my($japh,$q,$qq,%b)= "Just another Perl hacker\n";
    $_=join'',(
    07625127776,
    0122456410,
    03441733416,
    01420121552,
    04373570104,
    07143446334);s#9#f#;#s;#f#9#s;;
    s}9}b};$q=$_;*9=
    sub {
        $japh = "";
        print $japh;
    }; map { /^((?i)(?#q#;
    print $japh;#()[^
    for (my $(b) = 1; $(b) < $(q); \$b++;) {
        \/g])+[\](^.^)\[
    }
    ]*$/x?do{$qq=((ord)-96).(~~%b-$?)
    ;$/#;
    =$+;$q=~s/$qq/${\/}/g;}:9->({});
    }qw(
    a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
    );$qq=[$q,%b];$\=pack q*h\**
    ,qq$$.$$qq[0];9->();
```

I think a lot of it is extra/purely obfuscation. I get that we assign "Just another Perl hacker" to $japh, and we print it but we assign it to "" before we do so I don't get how that still works. Can someone explain what's going on here? Thanks!

Comment: Neat, SO correctly highlighted the `m//` operator.

Comment: where is it obfuscated?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Step № 1 to understand obfuscated Perl: run it through `-MO=Deparse`. Then, we get this output: (with a small syntax error removed)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my($japh, $q, $qq, %b) = "Just another Perl hacker\n";
$_ = join('', (1045737470, 21650696, 478656270, 205562730, 602861636, 965627100));
s/9/f/;
s/9/b/;
$q = $_;
*9 = sub {
    $japh = '';
    print $japh;
}
;
map {m{^((?i)(?#q#;
    print \$japh;#()[^
    for (my $(b) = 1; $(b) < $(q); \$b++;) {
        /g])+[\](^.^)\[
    }
    ]*$}x ? do {
    $qq = ord($_) - 96 . (~~%b - $?);
    $/ = $+;
    $q =~ s[$qq][$/]g
} : 9->({});} 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z';
$qq = [$q, %b];
$\ = pack('h*', '' . $$qq[0]);
9->();
```

Still not pretty, but better. Especially, this regex looks interesting:

```
m{^((?i)(?#q#;
    print \$japh;#()[^
    for (my $(b) = 1; $(b) < $(q); \$b++;) {
        /g])+[\](^.^)\[
    }
    ]*$}x
```

The `(?# ... )` is an embedded comment, which we can remove. Next on are the character classes

```
[^
    for (my $(b) = 1; $(b) < $(q); \$b++;) {
        /g]
```

and

```
[\](^.^)\[
        }
        ]
```

Here, they are equivalent to `[^bfgmoqry]` and `[\[\]()^.}\s]`, but as the regex will only ever be matched against single chars, the `[...]*` will match zero characters.

Thus, the regex is equivalent to

```
m/^([^bfgmoqry])$/
```

in this *special case* (being matched against `"a" .. "z"`).

The `*9 = sub {...}` assigns a coderef to a glob. Because `9` isn't a valid subroutine name, but can still be used with the `->` operator, `9->()` invokes that coderef. This is just like with `sub foo {...}`, `foo()` and `"foo"->()` are the same thing.

The char `a` is encoded as decimal `97` as ASCII, so `ord("a")-96` is `1`, for `z`, that would be 26.

The `$?` is the last child error, and should be zero. `$+` is the value of the last capture group (ergo, `$_`). The `~~%b` double-negates an empty hash. The scalarification of an empty hash is `0`, so double bitwise negation produces zero again.

The `$/ = $+; $q =~ s[$qq][$/]g` is just a bit obfuscation; as `$+` is `$_`, we could directly write `$q =~ s/$qq/$_/g`.

The `$qq = [$q, %b]; ... $$qq[0]` is lame, a `$\ = pack('h*', $q)` suffices.

In the `9` sub, the empty string will be printed, followed by `$\`, which is set to the empty string up to the penultimate line. Removing this level of indirection, and any now unused variables, as well as the simple substitutions, we get:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my $q = '1045737470216506f6478656270205562730602861636b65627100';
for ("a" .. "z") {
    m/^([^bfgmoqry])$/ or next;
    my $qq = ord($_) - 96;
    $q =~ s/${qq}0/$_/g;
}
print pack('h*', $q);
```

The `s/${qq}0/$_/g` substitution can only match at zeros, and we know that the output will be some hex-number for the `pack`. Possible positions for matching are:

```
1045737470216506f6478656270205562730602861636b65627100
*^      *^   *^          *^*^     *^*^             *^^
 a       g    e           g b      c f              a
```

of which `b, f, g` is forbidden due to the regex. The resulting string is

```
a45737470216e6f64786562702055627c602861636b65627a0
```

Which decodes to the JAPH.